# Wordpress: insert post-format in post using wp_insert_post()

Tags: wordpress, insert

as I can insert my php post using the format of a post ( example : post -format- quote ) using wp_insert_post ().

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post', // "post" para una entrada, "page" para páginas, "libro" para el custom post type libro...
    'post_status'   => 'publish', // "draft" para borrador, "future" para programarlo...
    'post_title'    => $_POST['BlogEntranceTitle'], 
    'post_content'  => $_POST['BlogEntranceCode'], 
    'post_author'   => $user_ID, //  
    'post_category' => $_POST['BlogEntranceCats'],  
    'tags_input'    => $_POST['BlogEntranceTags'],
    'post_excerpt'  => $_POST['BlogEntranceExcerpt']
);
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

achievement insert these options but I get no add format post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update post format separately because Post Format is a type of taxonomy. See following example for updating post format.

```
$my_post = array(
'post_type'     => 'post', // "post" para una entrada, "page" para páginas, "libro"     para el custom post type libro...
    'post_status'   => 'publish', // "draft" para borrador, "future" para programarlo...
    'post_title'    => $_POST['BlogEntranceTitle'], 
    'post_content'  => $_POST['BlogEntranceCode'], 
    'post_author'   => $user_ID, //  
    'post_category' => $_POST['BlogEntranceCats'],  
    'tags_input'    => $_POST['BlogEntranceTags'],
    'post_excerpt'  => $_POST['BlogEntranceExcerpt']
);
$new_post_id  = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
$tag = 'post-format-image';
$taxonomy = 'post_format';
wp_set_post_terms( $new_post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```

After inserting Post, Post ID is returned. That ID is used to update the post format. In the above example, `Image` post format will be assigned. Please change it as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Nilambar, great!! now place a variable ' post_format_type ' and it inserts the value in the table wp.
Thanks for your help!! =)

Answer (score 5):

For completeness: there is no need to 'decouple' or have this as a separate operation, as it can be set in the same array with the remaining settings. There is an [option](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) (namely, 'tax_input') to set taxonomies directly in the array containing the post parameters.

This is what I use to achieve the same effect:

```
$my_post = array(
   'post_type'     => 'post'                                     ,
   'post_status'   => 'publish'                                  ,
   'post_title'    => $_POST['BlogEntranceTitle']                ,
   'post_content'  => $_POST['BlogEntranceCode']                 , 
   'post_author'   => $user_ID                                   ,
   'post_category' => $_POST['BlogEntranceCats']                 ,
   'tags_input'    => $_POST['BlogEntranceTags']                 ,
   'post_excerpt'  => $_POST['BlogEntranceExcerpt']              ,
   'tax_input'     => array('post_format' => 'post-format-quote')  //  <- add this to set post_format
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: `'tax_input'     => array('post_format' => 'gallery') ` worked! thank you.