# Setting 'post_format' WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have the following code for my automated posting process file.

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $row['title'] ) ),
          'post_content'  => $content,
          'post_format' => 'audio',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_category' => array( 2 ),
          'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

You can see above that I have included `'post_format' => 'audio',` in my array but this does NOT seem to set the existing post format from "*standard*" to "*audio*" which is what I am trying to achieve.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlLUR.png).

Now this is where I started to hit some progress but I am still getting thrown at a dead end.

```
set_post_format($post->ID, 'audio' );
```

If I add this into my loop, upon editing my post it does in-fact change the format to *audio* but I have to manually edit the post for it to be changed which is an issue.

```
<?php       
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    set_post_format($post->ID, 'audio' );

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>
```

Above is my loop, at this point honestly any help is appreciated.. I am struggling to figure this out and would love to know how to automatically set it so that my `post_format` is defaulted to "*audio*" with every upload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090706/wordpress-insert-post-format-in-post-using-wp-insert-post

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `set_post_format()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_format